# Company EPS differs from 10-Q and 10-K

Tags: united-states, stocks, sec, earnings-per-share

I'm reviewing the 10-K filing of a company I'm thinking about investing in, and I came across some confusing information in my research. For FY20Q1/2/3 the EPS you can get from Fidelity, Yahoo, etc., refer to the EPS provided in their respective 10-Q. The *Condensed Consolidated Statements of Operations and Comprehensive Loss* and *Note 10: BASIC AND DILUTED LOSS PER COMMON SHARE* reflect this information directly; some quarterly data, however, differs in the 10-K, namely the *Note 19: UNAUDITED SUPPLEMENTARY QUARTERLY INFORMATION* section.

For FY20Q1, the weighted average number of common shares outstanding matches that in the 10-K, 107,618,908 shares. For FY20Q2 and FY20Q3, the values of their weighted average number of common shares outstanding do not transfer directly to the 10-K; in fact, they are much larger on the 10-K for each quarter.

Once more, the value in *Note 13: BASIC AND DILUTED LOSS PER COMMON SHARE* has a value of 121,168,136 shares but the aforementioned Note 19 shows 132,129,787 shares.

Why does the 10-K Note 19 section have differing quarterly values for their weighted average shares than on their respective 10-Q filings?

Edit: the company is Energy Fuels Inc (NYSE American: UUUU).

Comment: I would suggest that you add some links to the relevant documents/sections on EDGAR. This will make it easier for other users to investigate the problem.

Comment: most recent 10K: https://sec.report/Document/0001385849-21-000027/, most recent 10Q: https://sec.report/Document/0001628280-20-015184/

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that convertible debentures were translated into shares fast enough to account for the difference? They do mention it in the 10Q, although the company is saying that these options, warrants, and FCDs would be anti-dilutive, which is weird:

[image]